# VB.NET Attempted to divide by 0 error when Integer dividing by decimal

Tags: vb.net, zero, divide

I'm trying to do Integer division () by 0.25 but VB is telling me I tried to divide by zero, I also tried dividing by (1/4).

This is my snippet

```
AmountLeft = Remainder \ 0.25
lblQuartersAmount.Text = AmountLeft
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do integer division by a non-integer; just truncate and cast it afterwards.

```vb
AmountLeft = CInt(Math.Truncate(Remainder / 0.25))
```

And what's wrong with `* 4`? =)

Comment: Is it that you can't or is it that in this case .25 gets rounded to zero first?

Comment: @Kratz: Yep, it gets implicitly converted to an integer. So you can't do it on non-integers because they'll just become integers. Sorry.